# Change the default aplication when I plug in an iPhone on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, iphone, linux-mint

How can I change the default applications that start on my Linux Mint, when I plug in an iPhone?  Currently, what is happening is that banshee starts in couple of instances & crushes. I basically want it to do nothing just to keep it charging.

Answer (score 0):

Find System Settings (under System Tools) then choose the Details option (it's near the bottom). Choose the 'removable media' option and you will see that 'music player' is one media type - whatever you choose next to this option is what happens when you plug in your iPod. If you don't want any programs to open when you plug it in then choose the 'do nothing' option here.

Hope this help.